# Scrapy and long-running crawl

Tags: scrapy

I am running a long-running crawl to download images that fails after a while (about an hour). I get the following error:

```
[1]+  Killed scrapy crawl myScrapper
Killed
```

I don't have anything in particular in the log other than images being truncated:

```
exceptions.IOError: image file is truncated (1 bytes not processed)
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The file truncated issue seems to be a recurring problem with PIL. I tried without resizing images on a much bigger server and the process still dies once in a while.

Comment: I think what you are receiving is a marker image instead of original image like it happens on flickr.Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: For the image getting truncated? Actually they are very large images. I think PIL runs out of time or out of memory and truncates the image. But I've tried again to run long-running crawls without re-sizing images and they still stop with no errors.